# ZipArchive problem with Access to the process

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, c#-ziparchive

I try to do a function which of the files from the zip file will take two values ​​and update them in the GUI.
the problem is that i get exception about access to the file.

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\work\RasMol.zip' because it is being used by another process.'

```
      public void ReplaceEntry(string fileName)
    {
        var infoList = new List<RPPXFileEntry>();
        {
           
            ZipArchive Archive = ZipFile.Open(this.sourcePath, ZipArchiveMode.Update);
//exception in this place
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in Archive.Entries)
                {
                    var rppxEntry = new RPPXFileEntry();
                    if (entry.Name == fileName)
                {
                    rppxEntry.Modify = entry.LastWriteTime;
                    rppxEntry.Size = entry.Length;
                   infoList.Add(rppxEntry);
                }

            }
            this.AllEntries = infoList;

        }
    }
```

someone know how to deal with it?

Comment: Which tool create this archive? Maybe it also doesn't close the stream like you doesn't close  ```ZipFile.Open``` (it must be under ```using()```)

Comment: Missing `using` on `Archive` and `entry`